# formating a number/string with decimal separator

Tags: java, string-formatting, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am trying to format a Number with `DecimalFormat`. But I want it to format a number, that is like

```
input: 1234.  -->  should be formatted to: 1,234.
```

But I get `1,234.0` or `1,234.00` depending on my rules for the decimal format
What do I have to do in order to get this done?

Comment: What are your rules which results in wrong output?

Comment: Can you show the sample code of how you're using `DecimalFormat`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods that should help you are [setMinimumFractionDigits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits%28int%29) and [setMaximumFractionDigits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29).

```
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
```

at a guess, is probably what your looking for.

---

To ensure that the decimal separator is always shown, use: [DecimalFormat.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown%28boolean%29)

Comment: I am not able to get the output with the separator. Like input: 1. and output: 1.     only 1 or 1.0

Comment: Didn't catch that as a requirement the first time around.  Updated the answer to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

You could format the number regardless of whether it is a decimal or not by using

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#,###"); 
f.format(whatever)...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to display any decimal places, don't format a floating point value :) If you use `BigInteger`, `int`, or `long`, it should be fine:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {

    private static final char p = 'p';

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
        BigInteger value = BigInteger.valueOf(1234);
        System.out.println(format.format(value));
        System.out.println(format.format(1234));
        System.out.println(format.format(1234L));
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I want to display the point. It is like an Input and you add single values. So, I want the dot to be shown.

Comment: @user2118495: It's *very* unusual to show a decimal separator with no decimal digits after it. I don't remember ever seeing that in either a user interface or human writing. I wouldn't be surprised to find that it's not supported.

Comment: if I press the dot on several calculators, I get the separator without any number behind it. This is the way I want it. Like an usual calculator input.

Comment: @user2118495: But that's *while taking input* - not *formatting output*.

Comment: Yes. I format while taking the input. After every number that is read, I format. I added an answer.

Comment: @user2118495: No, you haven't added an answer... and I suspect you shouldn't reformat the input while it's still being typed.

Comment: I managed to figure it out, that's why I wrote this comment. I have to wait about 6 hours before I can answer. Didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(df.format(1234));
```